# Why does SFDX pull unwanted object data and how to prevent it

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata, .forceignore

I have an app that puts Lightning Web Components on the Flexipages of Accounts and Contacts. I also have a `Flexipage` for both in my App. I guess that is the reason for `SFDX` pulling in the object folders for both Objects.

As I don't modify any of that I also don't want to version those files.
What is the best approach to not have DX pull them?

- Not package the Flexipages at all
- Putting them in the `.forceignore`
- What else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use two things:

1. Use `.forceignore` for quite a lot e.g.

> ```
> # List files or directories below to ignore them when running force:source:push, force:source:pull, and force:source:status
> # More information: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_exclude_source.htm
> #
>
> package.xml
> **profile-meta.xml
>
> # LWC configuration files
> **/jsconfig.json
> **/.eslintrc.json
>
> # LWC Jest
> **/__tests__/**
>
> force-app/main/default/appMenus
>
> # Don't include the object definition, we're only adding the fieldset
> force-app/main/default/objects/Contact/Contact.object-meta.xml
> ```

I'd always exclude `**profile-meta.xml` because profiles just don't work well with DX. Then, anything that gets pulled by accident (e.g. `force-app/main/default/objects/Contact/Contact.object-meta.xml` gets added, too). This is just like your case - except I was adding a fieldset rather than a flexipage.

2. Use a second directory which doesn't get packaged. SF do this in some of their code examples. I use this for things I want in my scratch org (e.g. page layouts to do manual testing), but not in the org I'll install to.

For those, add two directories to sfdx-project.json:

```
"packageDirectories": [
    {
        "path": "force-app",
        "default": true,
        "package": "My Package",
        "versionName": "0.49",
        "versionNumber": "0.49.0.NEXT"
    },
    {
        "path": "unpackaged"
    }
```

And have two directory hierarchies: `force-app/main/default` and `unpackaged/main/default`.

When I do a pull of something like a page layout for a standard object where I've added a custom field, it ends up in `force-app`. But, I can move it to `unpackaged`, and sfdx will respect that. Any further pulls of changes to the page end up in the right place.

I check all of it into git so that when I check out, I'm ready to do manual testing.

Comment: I use the same approach but also have files in "unpackaged" that I actually wan to version. Like Apex classed to create Scratch Org data. Any solution to that? Just add a folder to .gitignore I guess?!

Comment: Looks like a typo in your comment? Maybe if you have three types of file, have three directories: force-app, unpackaged, and unversioned. Then .forceignore for unpackaged and .gitignore for unversioned

Comment: That's perfect! And yes there is a typo. I DON'T want to version ;-)

Comment: Darn! I moved objects into this unversioned folder and now get "Cannot delete managed object" on every push. I added { "path": "sfdx-source/unversioned" } to the sfdx-project.json

Comment: Try pushing into a fresh scratch org. Sometimes sfdx gets confused and you have to just try again with a new org :(