# Tests pass in scratch org, fail in package creation

Tags: apex, managed-package, scratch-org

I've written the following super simple Apex class and some tests for it (attached below):

```
public with sharing class BuyerStatusFetcher {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)  
    public static List<Opportunity> fetchBuyerStatus(String id) {
        return [
            SELECT 
                Opportunity.Id,

                Opportunity.namespace__Buyer__r.Name,
                Opportunity.namespace__Buyer__r.namespace__ID__c,
                Opportunity.namespace__Buyer__r.namespace__Check_Result__c
            FROM Opportunity
            WHERE Opportunity.Id = :id
        ];
    }
}
```

When I'm running the test in the Scratch org I use to develop, tests pass, even if I'm impersonating a user that lacks permission to see the custom objects.

However, when I run the tests during the package creation (with `--code-coverage`), it fails with the following error:

`Apex Test Failure: Class.namespace.BuyerStatusFetcherTest.testBuyerCreated: line 38, column 1 System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Opportunity.namespace__Buyer__r`

As other posts propose, I've created a fresh new Scratch org and ran the tests, and I got the same failure (bingo!). However, when I modify `fetchBuyerStatus` slightly, it works. I just need to add `Opportunity.namespace__Buyer__c` (the object that is in the lookup relationship).

```
public with sharing class BuyerStatusFetcher {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)  
    public static List<Opportunity> fetchBuyerStatus(String id) {
        return [
            SELECT 
                Opportunity.Id,
                Opportunity.namespace__Buyer__c,  // Added line
                Opportunity.namespace__Buyer__r.Name,
                Opportunity.namespace__Buyer__r.namespace__ID__c,
                Opportunity.namespace__Buyer__r.namespace__Check_Result__c
            FROM Opportunity
            WHERE Opportunity.Id = :id
        ];
    }
}
```

I've tried to create the package with `Opportunity.namespace__Buyer__c` directly, but it fails too. My theory is that on the first test call, when `Opportunity.namespace__Buyer__c` is added Salesforce generates under the hood something that allows me to use the `__r` relationship. However, I've performed a `sfdx source:pull` and I don't see changes in the code. The output of the command is the following:

```
Created Account-Account %28Marketing%29 Layout         Layout  force-app/main/default/layouts/Account-Account %28Marketing%29 Layout.layout-meta.xml         
 Created Account-Account %28Sales%29 Layout             Layout  force-app/main/default/layouts/Account-Account %28Sales%29 Layout.layout-meta.xml             
 Created Account-Account %28Support%29 Layout           Layout  force-app/main/default/layouts/Account-Account %28Support%29 Layout.layout-meta.xml           
 Created Opportunity-Opportunity %28Marketing%29 Layout Layout  force-app/main/default/layouts/Opportunity-Opportunity %28Marketing%29 Layout.layout-meta.xml 
 Created Opportunity-Opportunity %28Sales%29 Layout     Layout  force-app/main/default/layouts/Opportunity-Opportunity %28Sales%29 Layout.layout-meta.xml     
 Created Opportunity-Opportunity %28Support%29 Layout   Layout  force-app/main/default/layouts/Opportunity-Opportunity %28Support%29 Layout.layout-meta.xml   
 Changed Admin                                          Profile force-app/main/default/profiles/Admin.profile-meta.xml
```

My questions are:

1. Aren't the `Account-Account %28Marketing%29 Layout ...` pushed when performing `source:push`/creating the package and that is what is generating the issue? How can fix it during the package creation?
2. Why is the test working properly even if the user I'm impersonating doesn't have enough permissions?

**Edit:**

1. I was using a single directory with the metadata of my package and also some metadata that I needed during developing, but didn't want to include in the package. Once I splitted it into two (as described [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/270517/why-does-sfdx-pull-unwanted-object-data-and-how-to-prevent-it)), tests started working correctly (not sure why).
2. As Phil W mentioned below, Apex tests are ran in System mode, ignoring user permissions.

Tests (both pass when ran in the Scratch org, and fail when ran during the Package creation). The second one should fail as the user lacks permissions:

```
    @isTest 
    static void testBuyerCreated() {
        namespace__Buyer__c buyer = new namespace__Buyer__c(
            Name='Test Buyer',
            namespace__ID__c='11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111',
            namespace__Check_Result__c='APPROVED'
        );

        insert buyer;

        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
            Name='Test Opportunity',
            StageName='Prospecting',
            CloseDate=System.today().addMonths(1),
            namespace__Buyer__c=buyer.id
        );

        insert opp;

        Test.startTest();
        List<Opportunity> output = BuyerStatusFetcher.fetchBuyerStatus(
            opp.Id
        );
        Test.stopTest(); 

        System.assertEquals(output.size(), 1);
        System.assertEquals('Test Buyer', output[0].namespace__Buyer__r.Name);
        System.assertEquals('11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111', output[0].namespace__Buyer__r.namespace__ID__c);
        System.assertEquals('APPROVED', output[0].namespace__Buyer__r.namespace__Check_Result__c);
    }

    @isTest 
    public static void testUserPermissions() {

        User testUser = new User(
            ProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User'].Id,
            LastName = 'Test Standard User',
            Email = 'test@standarduser.com',
            UserName = 'test' + DateTime.now().getTime() + '@standarduser.com',
            Alias = 'alias',
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US'
        );

        insert testUser;

        System.runAs(testUser) {
            namespace__Buyer__c buyer = new namespace__Buyer__c(
                Name='Test Buyer',
                namespace__ID__c='11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111',
                namespace__Check_Result__c='APPROVED'
            );
    
            insert buyer;
    
            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
                Name='Test Opportunity',
                StageName='Prospecting',
                CloseDate=System.today().addMonths(1),
                namespace__Buyer__c=buyer.Id
            );
    
            insert opp;

            System.debug(opp);

            Test.startTest();

            List<Opportunity> output = BuyerStatusFetcher.fetchBuyerStatus(
                opp.Id
            );
            Test.stopTest(); 

            System.debug(output);

            System.assertEquals(output.size(), 1);
            System.assertEquals('Test Buyer', output[0].namespace__Buyer__r.Name);
            System.assertEquals('11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111', output[0].namespace__Buyer__r.namespace__ID__c);
            System.assertEquals('APPROVED', output[0].namespace__Buyer__r.namespace__Check_Result__c);
        }
    }
```

`sfdx-project.json`

```
{
   "packageDirectories": [
     {
       "path": "force-app",
       "default": true,
       "package": "Integration",
       "versionName": "1.0.0.0",
       "versionNumber": "1.0.0.0",
       "versionDescription": ""
     }   
   ],
   "name": "salesforce-integration",
   "namespace": "namespace",
   "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
   "sourceApiVersion": "57.0",
   "packageAliases": {...}
}
```

`project-scratch-def.json`

```
{
  "orgName": "Testing scratch org",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": ["EnableSetPasswordInApi"],
  "settings": { 
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Apex runs in system mode so if you do not do anything to explicitly apply user mode (in your query) then the data is loaded regardless of user permissions. As to the failure, is the namespace__Buyer__c field part of the package you are creating? If so, have you added this field within Opportunity as part of your package metadata?

Comment: Yes. I have the custom object in `force-app/main/default/objects/Buyer__c`, and then `force-app/main/default/objects/Opportunity/fields/Buyer__c.field-meta.xml` to include the lookup relationship between Opportunity and `Buyer__c`.

In addition, I've checked the included objects in a beta version of the package created without running the tests and both the Buyer__c custom object and the Opportunity.Buyer__c custom fields are included.

Comment: Does your `sfdx-project.json` include correct specification of the required namespace? And what about your `config/project-scratch-def.json`?

Comment: Best way is the [edit] the question to add these details, and use the markdown formatting.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! I've updated it.

Comment: Do you need to ensure the `versionNumber` is `1.0.0.NEXT` and define the `definitionFile` to point to `config/project-scratch-def.json`? Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.242.0.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev2gp_config_file.htm) for more detail.

Comment: In the end, I fixed the issue by splitting the metadata into two directories, and excluding from the package the metadata I didn't want to include on it. Not sure why it worked, but I was having a lot of issues creating the package due to this, probably due to my lack of experience. 

It worked both using the same version number several times while creating beta packages and I was including the definition file in the package creation command (`sfdx force:package:version:create --definition-file=config/project-scratch-def.json`)
Thanks for all the help!